# Can import of one DLL using ctypes cause a call to another to fail (python ctypes)?

Tags: dll, ctypes

This is my first post to the forum.  I am an inexperienced programmer who thought he was almost done with his first program only to run into a road block. I would hugely appreciate some insight on this problem.

I am writing a GUI to run two pieces of hardware: a motion control card (Precision MicroControl) and a data acquisition card (National Instruments).  So far I have successfully used Python's ctypes to import the required DLLs to run the devices separately.  All fine there.  However, when I attempt to use the two together a specific DAQ call fails and generates a NIDAQmx runtime error as well as a windows error:

NIDAQ Error - 50251 ' The specified software component is not available.  The component was not loaded'
windows error "PYTHONW caused an exception 10H in module NIESXU.DELL at 0167:6ef85ab5."

The initialization of the motion control card is one of the first things that happens in my program.  If I skip this part of the program, the DAQ works just fine.  As a matter of fact, a very simliar issue arises when I use matplotlib to create a figure in my program.  Program fails upon using the Tkinter 'grid' call, and it can be solved by excluding the motion control calls.

Can anyone give me a pointer on where the glitch might be?   Would be grateful for any leads.  I will try to supply more info if desired.

Some more info:
Windows 98 SE,
Precision MicroControl DCX-PC100,
DAQ PCI-MIO-16XE-50,
Python version 2.5

Simplified version of the program which doesn't work:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy

mcapi32 = windll.mcapi32  # motion control card DLL  # leave out this line...
hCtlr =mcapi32.MCOpen(arguments...)      # and this line, and the program works

def CollectNShots(n):  # set up to take n measurements
    mx = windll.nicaiu  #  load National instruments DAQ DLL
    TH0 = c_ulong()
    data.numpy.zeros((2*n,),dtype = numpy.float64)
    mx.DAQmxCreateTask(arguments)
    mx.DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan( arguments)  # here is where the error arises
    .....other DAQ commands.....

    return 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi all, I just found the answer.  Upgrading the software package for the motion controller did the trick.  Thanks for looking.